# Determining correlated product categories using store purchase history

Tags: clustering

I have a large dataset that contains product purchase history, like so:

```
userID  productID   category        subcategory
123     ABC         Kitchen         Knives
123     BEA         Kitchen         Organization
233     ZZS         Electronics     Phones
```

For a first project, I'm looking to answer the question: "What discrete groups of categories/subcategories do shoppers tend to shop in?". For example, we may find that shoppers who buy Monitors are highly likely to buy Keyboards and Mice as well.

Any direction on getting started on a problem like this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classic **market basket analysis**.

Clustering is the weong tool, you want frequent item set mining and association rules instead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. I'm currently exploring the arules library in R.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the twitter tag clustering problem. You can read literature around that for many ideas.

My personal starting approach would be to construct a network of `category` such that each unique category is a node and the strength between a pair of categories is determined by counting the number of customers who buy both products. Then you can look at some community detection algorithms in graph theory to form clusters of categories based on strength of pairs. Similar analysis can you repeated with `subcategory` and creating a combined variable of `category-subcategory`.